# Problema al reemplazar datos de una lista en una funcion de Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, funciones, matriz

El probema se trata de crear una matriz de un hotel, con ciertos pisos y ciertas habitaciones (filas y columnas, respectivamente)

Tengo que pedirle al usuario cuántos pisos y cuántas habitaciones hay (o sea el tamaño de la matriz) y a partir de ello crear una matriz nula. Esto lo hice en una función para poner validaciones sencillas y poder hacer recursividad si no se cumple la validación. Para ello hice la función así:

```
def definirHotel():                                                                  # creamos la matriz principal con la que se trabajará en todo el programa
cantPisos = input("Ingrese la cantidad de pisos: ")                              # cantidad de filas que debe haber
cantHabitaciones = input("Indique la cantidad de habitaciones por piso: ")       # cantidad de columnas que debe haber
pisos = []
hotel = []
i = 1
j = 1
try:    # validación
    cantPisos = int(cantPisos)
    cantHabitaciones = int(cantHabitaciones)
    while j <= cantPisos:
        while i <= cantHabitaciones:
            pisos.append(0)
            i += 1
        hotel.append(pisos)
        j+=1
    return hotel
except ValueError:
    print("Debe ingresar únicamente números.\n")
    return definirHotel()
```

El problema llega en otra función, en la cual debo solicitar al usuario cual habitación quiere alquilar, y también le solicito el precio que pagará por ella. Entonces básicamente debo reemplazar una celda específica de la matriz por un valor específico.

Hicimos este código:

```
def reservarHabitacion():
hotel = definirHotel()      # llamamos a la matriz principal de hotel
piso = input("\nIndique el piso en el que desea reservar: ")                     # usuario elige piso (fila)
habitacion = input("Indique el número de habitación que desea reservar: ")       # usuario elige habitación (columna)
monto = input("Indique el monto de hospedaje: ")                                 # valor que se sustituya en la celda especificada
try:
    piso = int(piso)                          
    habitacion = int(habitacion)              
    monto = int(monto)                          
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i <= piso:
        if i == piso:
            while j <= habitacion:
                if j == habitacion:
                    hotel[i-1][j-1] = monto
                j += 1
        i += 1
    return hotel
except ValueError:
    print("Ingrese solo números enteros.")
    return reservarHabitacion()
```

Ahora cuando imprimimos el nuevo hotel que genera esta última función

```
print(reservarHabitacion())
```

nos devuelve una lista como esta

```
[[50, 0, 0, 0, 0], [50, 0, 0, 0, 0], [50, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

nos está reemplazando el primer valor de cada fila, en vez de sólo uno.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normalmente el acceso a una lista de listas, o matriz de n x n es bastante simple en Python

```
hotel = [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
piso = 4
habitacion = 1

hotel[piso][habitacion] = 50
```

Sin embargo, si intentas hacer algo parecido desde una matriz generada por `definirHotel()`, obtienes el resultado que has mostrado, el valor se actualiza en la misma habitación de cada piso. Es un problema clásico, ocurre que los objetos lista que son mutables, se asignan por referencia, algo así:

```
piso = [1, 2, 3, 4]
hotel = [piso, piso, piso]
hotel[1][1] = 0 # Intentamos modificar solo elemento 1,1
print(hotel)

[[1, 0, 3, 4], [1, 0, 3, 4], [1, 0, 3, 4]]
```

Lo que ocurrió es que creamos `hotel` con tres elementos, pero que los tres referencian a la misma lista `piso`, una forma de verificarlo, es ver el identificador único de cada elemento:

```
print([id(e) for e in hotel])
[139719444487040, 139719444487040, 139719444487040]
```

Constatamos, que cada elemento de `hotel` es físicamente el mismo, por que cada uno es una referencia a un objeto con el mísmo `id`.

Este comportamiento se resuelve si al agregar cada nuevo elemento, hacemos una copia al vuelo del mismo, por ejemplo:

```
piso = [1, 2, 3, 4]
hotel = [piso[:], piso[:], piso[:]]
print([id(e) for e in hotel])
hotel[1][1] = 0
print(hotel)

[140544426708480, 140544426707776, 140544426708544]
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 0, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Y ahora haciendo un "slice" o recorte, pero completo de `piso` generamos una nueva lista, y ahora la referencia apunta a otra área de memoria.

En tu caso el problema lo tienes en `definirHotel` al hacer esto:

```
hotel.append(pisos)
```

reemplazalo por

```
hotel.append(pisos[:])
```

O bien de forma más explícita y con posibilidad de mayores opciones, puedes usar el método `copy()` de la propia lista:

```
hotel.append(pisos.copy())
```